# Passing url to Three20 TTURLMap

Tags: url, parameters, dictionary, three20

I am trying to pass in a URL as a parameter to a TTURLMap like this:

`[map from@"tt://person/(initWithURL:)" toViewController:
[PersonViewController class]];`

I then have a TTStyledTableItemCell with links that render like this:

`<a href="tt://person/http://persons.url.com/blah">Person name</a>`

but when I click on these links the link doesn't call the initWithURL:
method in the PersonViewConroller class.  I've verified things are
wired up correctly by passing in a simple string.  I believe this
isn't working because the parser thinks the URL is part of the
TTURLMap url mapping.  Is there a way to escape the person's feed url
(its a rest service that i need to use to pull info in)?

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only character that TTURLMap trips up on is the `/` character, so the following did the trick for me.  Just call these as Mike suggests on the way in and out of your init function

```
+ (NSString *)encodeTtUrl:(NSString *)str {
    NSMutableString *temp = [NSMutableString stringWithString:str];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"__" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    return [NSString stringWithString:temp];
}

+ (NSString *)decodeTtUrl:(NSString *)str {
    NSMutableString *temp = [NSMutableString stringWithString:str];
    [temp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"__" withString:@"/" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [temp length])];
    return [NSString stringWithString:temp];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a common problem.  I haven't found an elegant solution; the best I've been able to find is to manually escape the URL on the way in (e.g. by Base64-encoding it), and then manually unescape it inside your `initWithURL:` function.  (Actually, you'd probably want to have a function called `initWithBase64EncodedURL:` or something like that, for clarity.)